# Start doing Parastate node

Tags: nodes, blockchain

I was chosen as a Spartan of a Parastate. Who did according to the technical characteristics indicated in the guide?
CPU: 2.0 GHz x86-64 CPU
Memory: 8GB RAM
Disk: 500GB High-Speed Storage (SSD)
For your reference, we deploy our own ParaTime node on Azure D2s_v3 instances (2 VCPU, 8GB Memory, 500GB Disk space)
Did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I did the developer guide on github.
CPU: 2.0 GHz x86-64 CPU
Memory: 8GB RAM
Disk: 500GB High-Speed Storage (SSD)
For your reference, we deploy our own ParaTime node on Azure D2s_v3 instances (2 VCPU, 8GB Memory, 500GB Disk space).
My node is running.